# What is the quickest way to become a Khorne devoted human?

Tags: warhammer-40k, black-crusade

In [Black Crusade](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite.asp?eidm=154), what character progressions do I need to take to be considered a follower of Khorne, as quickly as possible?  Assume a non-chaos marine character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you become 'devoted' when you reach five advancements towards a specific chaos god.  So it's quantity, not quality, that we want.  Thus, the fastest way would likely be to ignore characteristics increases (Strength is for Khorne, but is expensive) and just buy up tier one talents and skills.  When I get home I'll take a look at the book, but I believe there are at least five talent advances that 'belong' to Khorne, and taking any five right away should have you become devoted within 1250xp (250xp per tier one talent, if my memory has not failed me).

EDIT:

Okay, looks like I was incorrect.  After consulting the book, it seems you need a minimum of twenty advances (and at least 10 corruption points to become aligned) in order to actually gain the favor of a chaos god.  Once you have reached twenty advances, if you have five or more advances more in favor of Khorne than any other chaos god, you end up devoted to Khorne.  This means the goal is to get to twenty advances and have at least five more advances that favor Khorne.

So it turns out the cheapest advancement is actually skills - a simple advancement (trained) is only 200xp, which is 50xp cheaper than any talent or characteristic advancement.  Knowing this, it seems the quickest way to get devoted to Khorne (I'm assuming you mean 'gain a Mark of Khorne') is to take Athletics, Command, and Parry, and then as many unaligned skills as possible at 'trained' level.  Then you should start purchasing tier one talents and characteristics advances (such as Strength [Khorne], WS [Unaligned], and BS [Unaligned]).  This will be your fastest route to twenty advances, and when done, you should be able to achieve your Mark of Khorne at twenty advances with the lowest amount of spent XP.

If you take any tier two talents or higher level advancements for characteristics or skills, you will require more XP before you get to twenty advances.  You might also wish to take a large number of 'unaligned' skills and talents, and save the majority of your Khorne advances for after you become aligned because they will become cheaper and the unaligned will remain the same cost.

Comment: A tier two talent counts as two advances, so the tier is not a problem.

Comment: Also, "follower" is just the five-advance imbalance. What also requires twenty advances is the Mark of the god.

Answer (score 11):

In the Black Crusade Core rulebook, page 75, it states

> Whenever a Heretic earns 10 Corruption Points (in other words, when they hit the thresholds of 10, 20, 30, and so-forth), they check Alignment. This means they compare how many Advancements they have purchased that are affi liated with each Chaos Power. If they have changed Alignment (by having five more advancements dedicated to any one Chaos Power than any other), then they switch their Alignment to the God in question. This may change the cost of any future Advances. The Heretic will not check Alignment again until 
>   the next Corruption Point threshold. (Also, Heretics pay costs for advancements based on their current Alignment, not the Alignment they may be trying to obtain in the future).

Thus If you have 5 more advancements in any one god than any other, when you pass a multiple of 10, you become aligned to that god.

The 20 threshhold that was mentioned is not for alignment, but rather for the individual Marks.  If you reach 20 advancements in a single god, then you check to see if you are aligned to that god.  If you have the 20 advancements and are aligned, you get the Mark of that god without having to obtain a Reward of the gods.

Comment: Welcome! Excellent citation.

Comment: You could add into the answer "multiple of corruption" or otherwise clarify that you mean corruption points.

Answer (score -4):

Well, I don't know the specific mechanics of Black Crusade but traditionally in the Warhammer universe if you dressed in red black and gold and went on an indiscriminate killing spree that is likely to mark you out as a follower of the Blood God.  In terms of character progression I guess that would translate as anything that helps you kill more things.

Comment: While this is a correct answer in terms of the game theme, I was looking for game mechanic suggestions.